# Combine data of two tables

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

table1 and it has columns

```
 id 
 sdate
 type
```

type column can have 2 values events or schedule i am using this query to get the result of total events and scheudle

```
 select date_format(sdate, '%m-%d-%Y') as sdate, sum( type ='event') as tevent , sum(type='schedule') as tschedule from table1 where sid ='1' group by (sdate);
```

table 2 has these columns

```
 id
 title
 dtime
```

to make them both similar to use in union i did something like this

```
 select date_format(dtime, '%m-%d-%Y') as sdate ,0 as tevent,0 as tschedule,count(id) as tlog from table2 where sid =1  group by (sdate) ;
```

I am bit confuse that how can i get data from both table in a way that if the date are same it should show me data in one column .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (includes some correction of the original queries):

```
select sdate, sum(tevent) as tevent, 
sum(tschedule) as tschedule, sum(tlog) as tlog
from (
select date_format(sdate, '%m-%d-%Y') as sdate, 
sum(type='event') as tevent , 
sum(type='schedule') as tschedule,
0 as tlog from table1
group by sdate
union
select date_format(dtime, '%m-%d-%Y') as sdate ,
0 as tevent,0 as tschedule,
count(id) as tlog from table2 
group by sdate 
) s group by sdate;
```

Comment: thanks but tevent and tschedule values are always getting incremented like in a table data is 0 but with this query it shows that 1

Comment: i change count to sum and it works
sum(type ='event') as tevent ,  sum(type='schedule') as tschedule

Comment: ah i see, that's smart. sum(if...) should do the same though. (not count, indeed)

Comment: and one correction u missed the from table1 , can u edit ur answer so i can make it correct so other will have no doubt left :)

Comment: indeed. I learned something new as well, I mean that short form for the condition-based sum :)